# How to use async json data?

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, asynchronous

I'm using node.js. 
I've managed to load and parse my .json file using async. 
The whole concept is very new to me, I can see my .json data in console but I'm not really sure how to actually use my data now,..

```
   async function getJsonFile() {
       let response = await fetch('example.json');
       let responsejson = await response.json();
       let str = JSON.stringify(responsejson);
       let jsonData = JSON.parse(str);

       return jsonData;
    };

    getJsonFile().then(console.log);  // I see my .json file in console, how can I use it ?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the way to do it:

```
var json = await getJsonData();
// use it
```

Comment: My question is how to actually use it, because right now I only know how to show in console with "console.log" but I can't seem to do anything else , everything I tried so far fails ; /

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use your data which is inside your json you can do this :

```
// Use this in an async function
const data = await getJsonFile();
// Then get value of one key
console.log(data.key); // from {key: "value"}, you'll get value
```

Answer (score 0):

To actually use what is in the JSON you need to store it as a variable and then access it in ways that are useful to you. You can access properties of objects using [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

```
// Save as variable
var json = await getJsonData();
// Do something with properties of data
console.log(json['key']);
```